# How to combine output columns into one using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to retrieve results and put fname and lname as single values of name column, how can I do that?

```
     ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
            pl.add(Projections.property("user.id").as("id"));
            pl.add(Projections.property("user.fname").as("fname"));
            pl.add(Projections.property("user.lname").as("lname"));
```

**Current output**

```
id  fname  lname
17  Alex   Moore
34  Jack   Segal
```

**Output should be**

```
id  name
17  Alex Moore
34  Jack Segal
```

Comment: `System.out.println(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName())`. Your database queries shouldn't mess with pure presentation logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for you would be to use either HQL or SQL queries as explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/queryhql.html)

```
select 
cat.weight + sum(kitten.weight)
from Cat cat
    join cat.kittens kitten
group by cat.id, cat.weight
```